# How to move Gmail sub-label out of hiearchy

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

In Gmail, I have some hierarchical labels:

`A/B/C`

I want to make C a top-level label, but can only find a way to rename it in its current position in the hierarchy or introduce a new hierarchical level.

I suppose I could apply a new label to all the mails in C, then remove the old hierarchical label, then rename the new label, but I wonder if I'm overlooking a more direct way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to **Mail settings**
2. Go to **Labels**
3. Search the label you want to un-nest
4. Click on the **Edit** link in the right side
   [image]
5. Uncheck **Nest label under:**
   [image]
6. Click **Save**

Comment: This doesn't work any more. I receive an error "The label name you have chosen already exists. Please try another name:"